# keep js value on css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm using a CSS animation on a div to appear or disappear this element.

here are my css animation :

```
@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0px, calc(20vh + 87.5px));
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0px, calc(20vh + 87.5px), 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0px, calc(20vh + 87.5px), 0);
  }
}
```

the problem is that on my css file I got a fixed height for my div: 350px;
when I add the fadeInDown animation on my js file with the setAttribute for my div, I disp it with a different height, but the problem is when I put the fadeout animation, it don't keep my changed height, but the fixed height on the css file (350px). So how can I keep the changed height?

Here is the code js :

```
check_existing_file_or_error_server(0, str_samefile); //i add the animation with the set attribute
document.querySelector(".error").style.height = 350 + ((samefile_check - 1) * 30) + "px"; // i change the height here
```

Comment: Can you share the minimum amount of HTML needed to reproduce ?

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve]. Right now it is very much unclear what you are asking, especially considering that your animation does not do anything to the height at all.